# How to set up SELinux to allow Apache to bind on port 888

Tags: linux, apache, http, selinux

I am trying to set the Apache server to listen on port 888 while [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) on permissive mode.

I successfully changed the httpd port to 888 and also done with the command:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 888
```

But still the connection is refused.

Comment: Make sure you add `Listen 888` to your Apache config files (probably /etc/apache2/ports.conf), and add a VirtualHost with port 888 and restart Apache. Also make sure you don't have a firewall blocking that port.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart service after all changes

Comment: restart is not helping

Comment: Make sure that your port is unblocked by firewall